# How can I tell Rails to autoload namespaced models from a top-level directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

How can I tell Rails (5 beta3) to look for namespaced models in `app/models` instead of in `app/models/namespace`?

I have

```
module MyApp
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
  end
end
```

and if I put it in `app/models/myapp` Rails finds it. However, since all my models will be within the `MyApp` module I'd rather keep them in `app/models`.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. I'm sure you know this. But, it seems like you're fighting Rails conventions on this one. I wonder if you're not better off just following the conventions. Not an answer to your question (sorry for that), just a thought.

Comment: Yes I know it and it would be the end of World if I have to use an extra folder but I'd like to know if there is a easy way to keep things cleaner.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't tell Rails to look for a qualified constant (like `MyApp::User`) at the top level of a directory in the autoload path like (`app/models`). When Rails sees `MyApp::User` (in code which is not inside a module definition) it will only look for `my_app/user.rb` in directories in the autoload path.

You could trick Rails a lot of the time by never using qualified constants. If your controllers are in the same namespace, the following would work:

app/controllers/my_app/users_controller.rb

```
module MyApp
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
module MyApp
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Rails doesn't know whether the `User` referenced in the controller is top-level or in `MyApp`, so it would look for both `app/models/user.rb` and `app/models/my_app/user.rb`. Similarly, you could autoload namespaced models in `app/models` from other namespaced models.

However, you'd hit a wall (that is, you'd have to manually require the model class file) as soon as you needed to refer to a namespaced model from code which was not itself in a namespace, e.g. in the console or in a unit test. And it would be silly to have controllers in a subdirectory but models not in a subdirectory. And you'd be confusing anyone who looked at your code. So the best thing to do would be to follow Rails convention and put your namespaced models in a subdirectory of `app/models`.